# How to expand variables in vim commands?

Tags: vim, variables, variable-expansion

I'm trying to get a variable expanded in a command call. Here's what I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=dir TlAddPm call s:TlAddPm(<f-args>)
function! s:TlAddPm(dir)
    let flist = system("find " . shellescape(a:dir) . " -type f -name '*.pm' | sort")
    TlistAddFiles `=flist`
endfun
```

At the `:` prompt, the `` `=flist` `` syntax seems to work (or, at least it did with a `w:` variable), but in the `.vimrc` file it doesn't — TlistAddFiles is just passed the string `` `=flist` ``.

---

Thanks to Andrew Barnett's and Mykola Golubyev's answers, I've now got this, which appears to work. Is there no better way?

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=dir TlAddPm call s:TlAddPm(<f-args>)
function! s:TlAddPm(dir)
    let findres = system("find " . shellescape(a:dir) . " -type f -name '*.pm' | sort")
    let flist = []
    for w in split(findres, '\n')
        let flist += [ fnameescape(w) ]
    endfor
    exe "TlistAddFiles " . join(flist)
endfun
```

Comment: what is the definition of TlistAddFiles?

Comment: It's from the taglist plugin http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/

Comment: do you call s:TlAddPm(dir) from the .vimrc?

Comment: yes, I call it from .vimrc ... see the command! line (the first line in the code example)

Comment: Check out your code refactoring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try just

```
let joined = join(split(flist))
exec 'TlistAddFiles '.joined
```

To your edit:

```
 let flist = split(findres, '\n')
 call map(flist, 'fnameescape(v:val)')
```

Comment: TlistAddFiles flist just passes the string flist.

Comment: TlistAddFiles string(joined)  .... passes string(joined). And the join() line complains that a list is required.

Comment: Yeah, the exec seems required.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
exe "TlistAddFiles `=".flist
```

might work.

Comment: Thats closer. Passes a string like View/JSON.pm^@View/TT.pm^@ ... just need to figure out how to split on null and also pass each to filenameescape.

Comment: FYI: I used exe "TlistAddFilesRecursive " . flist ... the `= stuff is weird syntax that makes the expansion work at the : prompt.

Comment: In that case, how about an 'xargs' at the end of your system string?

Comment: Well, that'd make problems for file names with spaces in them. But I've come up with something that (while ugly) works... See the question update.